# How to use type definitions in non typescript files using VSCode

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I have a non ts code like this:

```
// foo.js

module.exports = app => {
  // some logic here
}
```

I want to use typescript definition files to define the type of the argument `app`, so that VSCode will give me the intelisense

```
// foo.d.ts
interface App {
  name: string
  bar: number
}
```

then I do jsdocs in my js file:

```
// foo.js - updated
/// <reference path="./foo.d.ts" />
/**
 * @param {App} app
 */
module.exports = (app) => {

}
```

when I write `app.` it shows me the available properties.

But if I change my definition file so that it has dependencies:

```
import * as React from "react"

export interface App {
    name: string
    count: number
}
```

intelisense stops working.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Your `foo.js` is a module so your declaration file should describe it as a module as well. By adding `import` at the top of `foo.d.ts` file you are declaring a module - so far so good.

To consume your `foo` module you will have to use `import` keyword, for example (assuming the code below is in the file that is located in the same dir as `foo.d.ts`):

```
import {App} from './foo';

/**
 * @param {App} app
 */
module.exports = (app) => 
{
    console.log(app.count); //VSCode intellisence suggests name and count properties here
}
```

Comment: The code I'm writing is not typescript, so I cannot do `let c: foo.App` I just want to use typescript definitions for VSCode intelisense

Comment: This does not make any difference. You are declaring a module - therefore you must import it in order to use even in js. You can omit the typescript specifics here. The main point is that you must use `import` keyword.

Comment: How does importing ts definition file into js make sense?

Comment: You are not importing typescript definitions. You are importing javascript module -
 check the js syntax here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import. Definitions is there just for typing information and never being 'imported'.

Comment: You might have misunderstood my question. I have two files, one is typescript type definitions for my app and another is code for my app. I want to use this type definitions only for intelisense, I just want VSCode to understand what type of variable I'm working with using jsdocs.

Comment: If your js file represents a module (and according to your post it is) and you use it by importing (require) it - your definition file must reflect that. And it does now - as soon as it contains import - it becomes declaration of the module. If you work with modules (no matter ts or js) you must import them and that is what my post suggests.

Comment: I still don't understand, can you make a gist?

Comment: I have updated my answer with example for js instead of ts. Hope it will make it more clear of how to use modules with/without definitions.

Comment: Okay, that works like a charm for vscode, but how will this be processed by node/babel?

Comment: It will probably just fail to find file 'foo.js/jsx'

Comment: It will work just fine for node (and I assume babel) as it is plain javascript. d.ts file will be ignored and are not required for actual execution - they are never to anything even in typescript.

Comment: node doesn't even have `import` syntax yet, and babel will need additional loader to ignore such files.

Comment: yepp - you are right.I thought it already does. Using typescript hides this sort of problems.

Comment: Thanks for help anyway